# make: Convert .pdf files in a folder to .txt files without using loops

Tags: pdf, text, makefile

I want to convert all .pdf files in a folder into .txt files with make without using loops and with the help of *pdftotext*. The new .txt files shall keep the original file name. Additionally, the new file gets a new file extension.

Example:
test1.pdf --> test2.newextension

Everything's written within a Makefile file. I start the conversion by typing in "make converted" in my console.

My first (miserable) attempt was:

```
converted:
      @ls *.pdf | -n1 pdftotext
```

However, there are 3 things still missing with it:

1. It doesn't repeat the process
2. The new file extension isn't being added to the newly created files.
3. Is the original name being kept or being given to the pdftotext function?

I used to program with the bash and Makefile is completely new to me. I'd be thankful for answers!

Comment: You write that "_The new .txt files shall keep the original file name_" and you propose the example: "_test1.pdf --> test2.newextension_". This is not very clear. What do you mean with "_keep the original file name_"?

Comment: Your recipe `ls *.pdf | -n1 pdftotext` is very strange. Did you try it directly on the command line?

Comment: If you are completely new to make, you should probably start by reading some introduction about it. I suggest chapter 2 [An Introduction to Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) of the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this simple example:

```
SOURCES ?= $(wildcard *.pdf)

%.txt: %.pdf
        pdftotext $< $@

all: $(SOURCES:%.pdf=%.txt)

clean:
        rm -f *.txt
```

If no `SOURCE` was defined, it'll just try to get all `*.pdf` files from the local directory.

Then we define a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) teaching make how to make `*.txt` out of `*.pdf`.

We also define target `all` that tried to make a txt file [for each](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Computed-Names.html#index-computed-variable-name) `.pdf` file in `SOURCES` variable.

And also a `clean` rule deleting quietly all `.txt` files in current dir (hence be careful, potentially dangerous).